# miracle in sqlite GROUP BY statement

Tags: mysql, sqlite, group-by

I have a table which is grouped by city,side column for a unique entry, and I need to query latest entries of each city,side group. (newer entry always have higher timestamp value)

In SQLite I can use GROUP BY for the job: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6c1c4/1/0

but in MySQL, it doesn't work in this way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ead9/1/0

I think I misuse/abuse GROUP BY here, but how can I have a correct statement for by MySQL and SQLite?

Comment: what should be the outcome?

Comment: @bew I want the output like SQLite's output(i.e. the SQLite output is actually what I want), but with MySQL engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples, both MySQL and SQLite are breaking SQL standard.

In standard SQL (supported by all major SQL engines), if you use `GROUP BY` in `SELECT` statement, then the only expressions permitted in `SELECT` list are either columns listed in `GROUP BY`, or aggregate function calls (like `count()`, `sum()`, `avg()`, etc) over any other columns.

Most SQL engines: PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL, DB2 follow this rule strictly - they do not permit any other syntax.

Both MySQL and SQLite, however, decided to be more lax in that regard, which I think is big mistake and endless source for confusion. While it seems to work, it is absolutely not clear what is really happening. For example, SQLite timestamp column generated by your query does not look like anything that was present in original table source.

If you don't want to have any surprises, you should follow the standard. In your case, it means using statement like:

```
SELECT
    min(period),
    side,
    city,
    min(gold),
    min(silver),
    min(normal),
    min(timestamp)
FROM cities
GROUP BY city, side
ORDER BY min(timestamp)
```

When you use it, both MySQL and SQLite (and any other database for that matter) return identical results: [SQLFiddle for MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec252/3), [SQLFiddle for SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ec252/3).

---

**UPDATE**:
  This statement will do what you want in standards-compliant SQL:

```
SELECT
    c.period,
    g.side,
    g.city,
    c.gold,
    c.silver,
    c.normal,
    g.timestamp
FROM cities c,
   (SELECT
       side,
       city,
       max(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM cities
    GROUP BY city, side) g
WHERE c.side = g.side
  AND c.city = g.city
  AND c.timestamp = g.timestamp
ORDER BY c.timestamp
```

It generates identical result for both [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec252/9) and [SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ec252/4).
(There is only one catch: it assumes that timestamp is unique per group).

Comment: but the result of this statement is not what I want(the SQLite result in my question **is** what I want exactly)

Comment: Then use standard SQL to get what you want - first of all you should explain what is that you want, exactly (but without pointing to SQLite result). Using `*` with `GROUP BY` does not make sense, if you think about it a bit more. Fact that this is permitted by both SQLite and MySQL does not make it admissible.

Comment: OK. What I need to do is that, get the latest entry(which has larger timestamp value) of each (city,side) group.

Comment: Now we are talking. "Has largest timestamp value" is aggregate function `max()`, and this is something that `GROUP BY` understands. I have updated an answer to provide standards-compliant query for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any aggregating functions (and I'm talking specifically about MySQL here), the use of a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate and meaningless. Perhaps you meant to use the DISTINCT operator.